# How to set download location for a link?

Tags: download

I want to create a link where when I click on it, it will download a file to a specific location (the Desktop) on the user's computer (basically the "save link as..." dialog will pop up with the Desktop as the default location).

Is this possible at all? Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

That is a user setting and you cannot force the user to download a file to a specific directory.  The best thing you can do is to link to the file and allow the user to choose the correct place to save the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
is there any way i could "suggest" a location to load up on the dialog box?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, sorry!