# How change the default download location in PHP

Tags: php, file, download, gmail, inbox

my code:

```
$zip_name="download.zip";
$ctype="application/zip";

// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");

// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($zip_name)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zip_name));
readfile("$zip_name");
```

now files download on Downloads folder.

i need download all files in D: drive.

Comment: I don't think any browsers support this since it would be quite a securtiy threat to allow the website to determine where files should be placed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832486/how-to-set-download-location-for-a-link

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible. A webserver cannot tell a client where to save a file. Imagine the security implications if a site could specify an exact location for a file save operation.

See [RFC 2183, section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.3):

> **The receiving MUA SHOULD NOT respect any directory path information
>
> that may seem to be present in the filename parameter**.  The filename
> should be treated as a terminal component only.  Portable
> specification of directory paths might possibly be done in the future
> via a separate Content-Disposition parameter, but no provision is
> made for it in this draft.

Comment: @Sammaye thanks for your  reply.i am working on this script. today is last day.if i found the script.i will post here.